# What proper method to route throung chain of states in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-routing, angular-router

I'm implementing signup service, where user suggested to choose three parameters: building (salon), service and company (category). I use `ui-router` for `AngularJS` for this task.

I've created prototype with six nested in each other states like so:

```
angular.module('ngApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.router'])
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$stateProvider
  .state('form', {
    url: '/form',
    template: '<div ui-view></div>',
    controller: 'dummyController'
  })
  .state('form.salonChoose' ,{
    url:'/salChoice',
    template: '<button ng-click="changeSalon()">salon 99</button>'
  })
  .state('form.salons', {
    url: '/salons/:salonId',
    template: '<div>{{model.salon}}</div>' +
    '<div ui-view></div>',
    controller: function($scope, $stateParams) {
      $scope.model.salon = $stateParams.salonId;
      location.href = '/#/form/salons/'+$scope.model.salon+'/serviceChoice';
    }
  })
  .state('form.salons.serviceChoice', {
    url:'/serviceChoice',
    template: '<button ng-click="changeService()">service 99</button>'
  })
  .state('form.salons.services', {
    url: '/services/:serviceId',
    template: '<div>{{model.service}}</div>' +
    '<div ui-view></div>',
    controller: function($scope, $stateParams) {
      $scope.model.service = $stateParams.serviceId;
      location.href = '/#/form/salons/'+$scope.model.salon+'/services/'
        +$scope.model.service+'/catChoice';
    }
  })
  .state('form.salons.services.catChoice', {
    url:'/catChoice',
    template: '<button ng-click="changeCat()">cat 99</button>'
  })
  .state('form.salons.services.categories', {
    url: '/categories/:catId',
    template: '<div>{{model.cat}}</div>',
    controller: function($scope, $stateParams) {
      $scope.model.cat = $stateParams.catId;
    }
  });
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/form/salChoice');
```

This approach works in such an implementation. Simple use case to be passed: 
run app with custom url: `#/form/salons/1/services/2/categories/3` and it should will be at state `form.salons.services.categories`. And prototype works good.

But when I use such an approach in my production app, states going to be not changed after first first change. The difference is that in production nested states had to use same `ui-view` instead of nested, I think it's tha point, why states not changed.

What the proper way to approach state changing while url having been parsed?

Comment: Have you tried `$state.go()` method for doing this

Answer (score 1):

For getting a basic idea how states should work you can  see [this github example](https://github.com/noman57/login).

for changing states use

```
$scope.changeState = function () {
    $state.go('any.state.you.want.', {param: param});
};
```

by using something like this

```
<button ng-click="changeState()">Another state</button>
```

Comment: I found one mistake, $state is undefined. Is it service?

Comment: I've fixed previous error. Now I see, that `$state.current` object after executing `$stat.go('form.salons.services')` is the correct state, but DOM has not changed, it suit for parent state's view. View not changed.

Comment: meaning you might be pointing to the wrong view .. state would oviously change views also